# Is there a way to detect the type of a variable in Applescript?

Tags: types, applescript

So I have a variable that could have different types(string, number, list, etc.). Is there a way to check for the type of a variable? So something like this:

```applescript
if type of x = list then return true
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it right. Instead of `type`, use `class` and it will work. Be wary though, there are some sneaky exceptions:

```applescript
log class of 1 -- (*integer*)
log class of 1 = integer -- (*true*)
log class of 1 = number -- (*false*)
log class of "1" -- (*text*)
log class of "1" = string -- (*true*)
```